# executable program is not recognized by cmder even though I have added its directory to system PATH

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, path, cmder

Recently I installed Pandoc and added its install directory to my system PATH. But I found that I can execute the program only in the system `cmd`, not in `cmder`.

I reinstalled the `cmder` program and the `pandoc` command can be executed in `cmder` miraculously. Today, I can not execute the command in `cmder` again (still can execute the command in `cmd`), which is weird.

I have read some `cmder` issue, e.g., [issue #443](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/443) and [issue #792](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/792), which are related to mysql. In my case, there is no `&` character in the Pandoc path, the full path is `C:\Users\east\AppData\Local\Pandoc`.

If I directly add the Pandoc path in `cmder` console, 

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\east\AppData\Local\Pandoc;`

I can also execute the `pandoc` command.

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: You should check the `PATH` variable of course. Did you execute `set PATH` in cmder? Did you try `where pandoc`? At last, run [Process Explorer](https://conemu.github.io/en/ProcessExplorer.html) and check the `PATH` in the parent processes of your consoles. More reading: https://conemu.github.io/en/WindowsEnvironment.html

Comment: I have checked the outputs of `echo %PATH%` in both `cmd` and `cmder`: output of former contains the path to pandoc executable while output of latter does not. I use `set PATH` in cmder. `where pandoc` shows `C:\Users\east\AppData\Local\Pandoc\pandoc.exe` in `cmd` and can not find the file in `cmder`.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was PATH referencing another user variable.  When I typed `echo %PATH%` in cmder those variables expanded which made me think all was fine.  However typing the same in the default windows command prompt showed those variables were not expanded.

Solution: Update PATH to the expanded path those variables reference